# How to express the quality of being fried?

Tags: expressions

I want to express the good quality of being fried of some dumplings, the way their almost redness and crispiness etc...

What words or expressions would you use to do that?

Comment: ["Fry 3 or 4 dumplings at a time, turning once, until _golden brown and crisp_."](http://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/fried-shrimp-dumplings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already expressed two qualities "almost redness" and "crispiness". As for other words, it depend on what aspects you wish to describe.  Some fried foods have a distinctive aroma; some are spicy, some salty, some sweet; some a combination of these.

A dumpling's exterior can be soft, or it might be crusty, maybe even flaky (if made with phyllo or rice paper); the interior could be succulent, juicy, or dry, or chewy, or soft enough to melt in your mouth (fried mozzarella sticks come to mind).

There are probably hundreds of words in English to describe food texture, aroma and flavor. Read restaurant menus; they are filled with adjectives designed to entice. And use a thesaurus to find words similar to the ones I mentioned above.